# AspNetCoreRateLimit prevented from working on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, rate-limiting

I am hosting our app on Azure and the `Insights` logs shows that all requests coming into the application are logging `0.0.0.0` as the `client_IP`.

For example, this `kusto` query:

```
requests
| where client_IP != '0.0.0.0'
```

...returns no results.

As the app uses the [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/ClientRateLimitMiddleware#setup) package to rate limit user requests for one particular endpoint, the net effect appears to be that **all users** are rate limited, rather than on a per user basis.

My understanding is that if `Insights` can't get the client IP address, then our code (and any NuGets it uses) will not be able to, either.

Is it a fair assumption that it is Azure which is preventing both Insights and our code from acquiring the client IP address? If that is a possibility, how could I confirm that?

Comment: Hi Matt, just to follow up, did you get any further with this question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a fair assumption that it is Azure which is preventing both Insights and our code from acquiring the client IP address? If that is a possibility, how could I confirm that?

App Insights doesn't store the ip [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=net):

> By default IP addresses are temporarily collected, but not stored in Application Insights.
> ...
> This behavior is by design to help avoid unnecessary collection of personal data. Whenever possible, we recommend avoiding the collection of personal data.
> ...
> To enable IP collection and storage, the DisableIpMasking property of the Application Insights component must be set to true. This property can be set through Azure Resource Manager templates or by calling the REST API.

So your code should still be able to collect ip addresses.